# How to get the sum of the filtered data in shinyapp

Tags: r, shiny, dynamic-columns, filtered

I'm trying my first shinyapp using two filters. The output would be two; the first to get a data table and the second to get the sum of the filtered output.

The data consists of 4 variables;
Welfare_benefit - character
Value - Numerical
Category - character
Targeted_group - character

Data - Budget2023

Code:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(readxl)
library(shinythemes)

Budget2023 <- read_excel("Budget2023.xlsx", 
                         sheet = "Welfare benefits for R")

Budget2023$`Value_in_Rupees_Million` <- as.numeric(Budget2023$`Value_in_Rupees_Million`)

ui <- fluidPage(

 theme = shinytheme("superhero"),
    titlePanel("Budget 2023 - Welfare allocations"),

    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            selectInput("category",
                        "Select category",
                        choices =   Budget2023$`Broad_categories identified`),
        selectInput("group",
                    "Select the targeted group",
                    choices = Budget2023$`Targetted_group`)
            ),

        # Show a plot of the generated distribution
        mainPanel(
           tableOutput("WelfareTable"),
           textOutput("Total")
        )
    )
)




server <- function(input, output) {

  
output$WelfareTable <- renderTable( { 
  if (input$category == "") {
    subset(Budget2023, input$group == Budget2023$`Targetted_group`)
  } else {
    subset(Budget2023, input$category == Budget2023$`Broad_categories_identified` & input$group == Budget2023$`Targetted_group`)
  }
  })  


output$Total <- renderText(c(sum(Budget2023$`Value_in_Rupees_Million`))) 


# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The issue is it doesn't generate the sum of the columns filtered and generated in the Welfaretable output.

Appreciate if you can assist on this as I couldn't figure out the issue through existing examples.

TIA!

Edit:

```
Dataset - Budget2023

Budget2023 <- DF ( Welfare_benefit = c('A','B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'),
                   Value_in_Rupees_Million = c(43000, 67000, 3000, 250, 5700,340, 3100), 
                   Broad_categories_identified = c('Economic', 'Education', 'Health', 'Education', 'Livelihood', 'Education'),
                   Targetted_group = c('Elderly', 'Disabled', 'Children', 'Low income', 'Elderly', 'Disabled', 'Disabled'))
```

Comment: Can you share a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Maybe first 10-20 rows of your dataset.

Comment: This example data set is still bad. There is no column such as "Broad categories identified". Please check before share all the columns in dataset. And please share it like `Budget2023 <- data.frame(welfare_benefit = c('A','B'), rupees = c(43000, 67000), category = c('Economic', 'Education'), targeted_group = c('Elderly','Disabled'))`. It's really hard to work with column names have spaces.

Comment: My apologies. Will edit the main post....

Comment: one of the columns in your sample data has 6 values, others have 7, the server function is missing `}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the text output in your code is not using the subset table, but taking sum of all your `Budget2023` dataset. try this, I'm using a `reactive` that generates the subset using `input` selections and use it in the output table and text calculating sum.

```
Budget2023 <- data.frame( Welfare_benefit = c('A','B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'),
     Value_in_Rupees_Million = c(43000, 67000, 3000, 250, 5700,340, 3100), 
     Broad_categories_identified = c('Economic', 'Education', 'Health', 'Education', 'Livelihood', 'Education', 'Education'),
     Targetted_group = c('Elderly', 'Disabled', 'Children', 'Low income', 'Elderly', 'Disabled', 'Disabled'))

ui <- fluidPage(
  theme = shinytheme("superhero"),
  titlePanel("Budget 2023 - Welfare allocations"),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("category", selected = "", # initial value
                  "Select category",
                  choices =   Budget2023$Broad_categories_identified),
      selectInput("group",
                  selected = Budget2023$Targetted_group[1], # initial value
                  "Select the targeted group",
                  choices = Budget2023$Targetted_group)
    ),
    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("WelfareTable"),
      textOutput("Total")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  subset_data <- reactive({
    if (input$category == "") {
      subset(Budget2023, input$group == Budget2023$Targetted_group)
    } else {
      subset(Budget2023, input$category == Budget2023$Broad_categories_identified & input$group == Budget2023$Targetted_group)
    }
  })
  
  output$WelfareTable <- renderTable( { 
    subset_data()
  })  
  
  output$Total <- renderText(sum(subset_data()$Value_in_Rupees_Million))
}
  
  # Run the application 
  shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```